# k6 test is only executing "http" request simulatenously and websocket request consecutively

Tags: javascript, websocket, load-testing, k6

I created different modules for my http and websocket requests. Below is a sample structure.

```js
import http from "k6/http";
 import {loginReq} from "./lib/login.js";
  import {onOpen, respMsg, close, searchItem} from "./lib/handler.js"

 export default function() {
    let jsess = loginReq();
      
      let params = {
      "JSESSION":jsess
      };
      
      let reqMsg ={
      open: onOpen,
      message: respMsg,
      close: close,
      fn:{
      searchItem: searchItem
      }
      };
      
      let response = ws.connect(url, params,  reqMsg);
      
      check(response, { "status is 101": (r) => r && r.status === 101 });
 }
```

loginReq() function is an http request while my searchItem is a websocket request.

I was just wondering whenever I execute the command

> k6 run --vus 10 --duration 10s

my loginReq function(which is an http) gets executed 10 times simultaneously (as expected with 10 vus), and then it starts executing my searchItem(websocket) one after another.

Sample logging:

```js
.....
created user 11
searching for item...
search successful!
created user 12
searching for item...
search successful!
.
.
.
created user 20
searching for item...
search successful!
```

All my functions are called inside the export default function, however, it seems that VUS are only executing the "http" requests simultaneously while my websocket requests aren't. Has anyone experienced the same way? Any suggestions on how I can work around with the execution behavior?

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce the error, with the following script, but it is working as expected.

Just run `k6 run --vus 5 -i 5 script.js`

```
import ws from "k6/ws";
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check, sleep } from "k6";

export default function () {
    http.get("http://test.loadimpact.com");
    console.log(`exec http.get at ${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()}`)

    sleep(1)

    var url = "ws://echo.websocket.org";
    var response = ws.connect(url, {}, function (socket) {
        socket.on('open', function open() {
            console.log(`VU ${__VU} ==> connected at ${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()}`);
            socket.ping();
        });

        socket.on('ping', function () {
            console.log("PING!");
        });

        socket.on('pong', function () {
            console.log("PONG!");
        });

        socket.on('close', function close() {
            console.log('disconnected');
        });

        socket.on('error', function (e) {
            if (e.error() != "websocket: close sent") {
                console.log('An unexpected error occured: ', e.error());
            }
        });

        socket.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('1 seconds passed, closing the socket');
            socket.close();
        }, 1000);
    });

    check(response, { "status is 101": (r) => r && r.status === 101 });
};
```

You'll see that they are all connecting to the WebSocket at the same time.

```
k6 run --vus 5 -i 5 script.js

          /\      |‾‾|  /‾‾/  /‾/
     /\  /  \     |  |_/  /  / /
    /  \/    \    |      |  /  ‾‾\
   /          \   |  |‾\  \ | (_) |
  / __________ \  |__|  \__\ \___/ .io

  execution: local
     output: -
     script: script.js

    duration: -,  iterations: 5
         vus: 5, max: 5

INFO[0001] exec http.get at 05/15/2018, 12:22:11
INFO[0001] exec http.get at 05/15/2018, 12:22:11
INFO[0001] exec http.get at 05/15/2018, 12:22:11
INFO[0001] exec http.get at 05/15/2018, 12:22:11
INFO[0001] exec http.get at 05/15/2018, 12:22:11
INFO[0002] VU 2 ==> connected at 05/15/2018, 12:22:12
INFO[0002] VU 1 ==> connected at 05/15/2018, 12:22:12
INFO[0002] VU 4 ==> connected at 05/15/2018, 12:22:12
INFO[0002] VU 5 ==> connected at 05/15/2018, 12:22:12
INFO[0002] VU 3 ==> connected at 05/15/2018, 12:22:12
INFO[0002] PONG!
INFO[0002] PONG!
INFO[0002] PONG!
INFO[0002] PONG!
INFO[0002] PONG!
INFO[0003] 1 seconds passed, closing the socket
INFO[0003] disconnected
INFO[0003] 1 seconds passed, closing the socket
INFO[0003] disconnected
INFO[0003] 1 seconds passed, closing the socket
INFO[0003] disconnected
INFO[0003] 1 seconds passed, closing the socket
INFO[0003] disconnected
INFO[0003] 1 seconds passed, closing the socket
INFO[0003] disconnected
```